# How can I set using of "WHSUserPermission" class?

Tags: c#

How can I set using of "WHSUserPermission" class?
I don't find microsoft.homeserver.sdk.interop.v1.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the Windows Home Server SDK.  That isn't provided as a redist (according to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425866.aspx)), you have to copy the files directly from `%ProgramFiles%\Windows Home Server\` on your Home Server's drive.

Comment: do you know from where can I download WindowsHomeServerSDK.dll?

Comment: As I said, it's not provided as a redistributable (i.e. you can't download it).  You have to copy it from a home server computer, from the folder I mentioned.

Comment: I don't find it, can you sent me to mail: sarikaner.gmail.com?

Comment: I don't have it either; I'm just reading the documentation.  If you have a Windows Home Server then you should find it in the folder mentioned.